# ng-repeat on multilevel object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have to repeat over an array.
My request looks like this:
[image: this is what I get when I console log the object]

I can repeat over the time masks like this:

```
<md-list-item ng-repeat="timeMask in timeMasks" ng-click="selectTimeMask(timeMask)">
    <span>{{timeMask.name}}</span>
</md-list-item>
```

Now I am trying to get the day in timeMaskInterval but I could not manage to do it. Currently my code looks like this:

```
<md-list-item ng-repeat="timeMask in timeMasks.timeMaskInterval">
    <span>{{timeMaskInterval.day}}</span>
</md-list-item>
```

How can I use ng-repeat on multi-level?

Comment: shouldn't it be <span>{{timeMask.day}}</span> ?

Comment: @Rabi does not work, but the both answers solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this :

```
<md-list-item ng-repeat="timeMask in timeMasks" ng-click="selectTimeMask(timeMask)">
<md-list-item ng-repeat="interval in timeMask.timeMaskInterval">
<span>{{interval.day}}</span></md-list-item></md-list-item>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the second repeat to get the Days , should reference for the current timeMask which again contains the array of days (so ng-repeat needs to be added for the timeMask not timeMasks),
use like `timeMaskDays in timeMask.timeMaskInterval`

```
<md-list-item ng-repeat="timeMaskDays in timeMask.timeMaskInterval">
        <span>{{timeMaskDays.day}}</span>
    </md-list-item>
```